# Repeat a form and passing it custom objects

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

In my VF page I have a form which uses map of a hardcoded custom object for some operations (Schema.Sobjecttype.object1_c.fields.getMap()).

Now I want to repeat this same form three times in the same page each time it takes a different custom object.

```
<apex:page>
<apex:repeat .... give the 3 custom objects in a loop>
<apex: form>
//form code
</apex:form>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

The form code is done inside a controller. So I want to know if I can give a list of sobjects to loop through and if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the form a visualforce component and use the object name as a parameter for the component. Then in the component controller, load the getMap() for that object and show in the component.